# How to round *down* integers in Java?

Tags: java, numbers

I'd like to round integers down to their nearest 1000 in Java.

So for example:

- 13,623 rounds to 13,000
- 18,999 rounds to 18,000
- etc

Comment: Do you mean round down, or round to zero? There's a difference when the numbers can be negative.

Comment: actually i mean round down so i have just thousands to deal with, i.e. 43,844 rounds down to 43,000 (not 44,000)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simply divide by 1000 to lose the digits that are not interesting to you, and multiply by 1000:

```
i = i/1000 * 1000
```

Or, you can also try:

```
i = i - (i % 1000)
```

Comment: +1: I never thought to use modulus this way.  Also, you can shorten the line slightly by doing `i -= i % 1000` (dunno if parentheses are required around the right side or not)

Comment: Really? I always thought of modulus as a way to get the units of a number (`i % 10`) etc. 
Regarding the shortened version - that's probably what I'd do in my code, but wanted it to be clear here.

Comment: @jasons please check the OP's description, he wants this behavior (basically wants the "number of whole thousands")

Comment: OP does not specify behavior for negative numbers. When asked about round down or rounding towards zero, said "actually I mean round down" but wasn't particularly clear.

Answer (score 12):

You could divide the number by 1000, apply [`Math.floor`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)), multiply by 1000 and cast back to integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = Math.floorDiv(-13623, 1000) * 1000 
//i => -14000
```

The above code will always round down (towards negative infinity) assuming the divisor (1000 in the example) is positive.

The other answer (`i = i/1000 * 1000`) rounds down when `i` is positive, but up when `i` is negative.

```
-13623 / 1000 * 1000 == -13000
```

There is also a version of `Math.floorDiv` for `long`s which will work for very large numbers where the `Math.floor` method might fail due to the precision of `double`.

There are also `Math.floorMod` methods to go with the `floorDiv`s which might allow you to shorten it a bit:

```
int i = -13623;
i -= Math.floorMod(i, 1000);
//i => -14000
```