# Integer division in Scala

Tags: scala

I've noticed that in Scala, `2 / 3` and `-2 / 3` both evaluate to 0 (while `-4 / 3` evaluates to -1.  What's the best way to define an integer division function where `2 / 3` evaluates to 0, `-2 / 3` evaluates to -1, and `-4 / 3` evaluates to -2, as it does in Python?  I'm sure I could use an if statement to handle positive and negative numbers differently, but is there a nicer way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457208/java-how-do-i-perform-integer-division-that-rounds-towards-infinity-rather-tha

Comment: I don't have a quick answer for you, but the answer will lie in the rounding behavior of the two languages.  With integers like this, scala effectively truncates the fraction, whereas python will round toward negative infinity.

Comment: Even though it's Scala vs Java, I think this is enough of a duplicate of the link provided by @ZhekaKozlov that I am going to close it.  If anyone else disagrees then vote to have it reopened.