# Split Number into equal periodic values

Tags: java

I have been given min and max number,

e.g: min = 10 and max = 1000 now i want to split this number into equal parts and in result i should get 10 numbers.

like: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 , 800 , 900, 1000

this we can do by dividing max with number we want e.g: 1000/10 and add 100 every time.

but, there is one scenario in which we have been given :
min = 14 and max = 1113 in this case if we divide 1113/10 then we will get 111

and the range will come like 0 , 113, 226, 339 ...

but, i don't want to show them like this . It would be better if i can display 110 or 115 or 120 even numbers (round off) instead of 113.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: How do you decide how much to "round off"? Do you want to always round to the nearest multiple of 10? The nearest multiple of 5? Or something else?

Comment: Your algorithm is not clear. Why would you round that way?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice excatly

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca nearest multiple of 5 or 10 for odd numbers

Comment: @Rohitesh Choose one. Then google how to round that way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks i think i should try this way

Comment: @Rohitesh Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when `min=14` and `max=1113` you divide 1113/10 to get 111. If you want to round 111 down to 110, you can perform `111 - (111 % 10)` to get 110. Then simply iterate 10 times and multiply the beginning number by the current iteration.

There is a similar post to this here: [How to round *down* integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783519/how-to-round-down-integers-in-java)

Depending on what numbers you want to display (either 110 or 115 or 120) you can approach this in a similar way.

Comment: You should include the relevant information in your answer, not as a link

Answer (score 0):

That is an algorithm for scaling a diagram; distributing ticks on an axis.
However 10 ticks is then an over-estimate.

```
private int[] ticks(int min, int max) {
    int gap = (max - min) / 10;
    // Round gap up to a nice value - best calculatory:
    if (gap < 1) {
        gap = 1;
    } else if (gap < 5) {
        gap = 5;
    } else if (gap < 10) {
        gap = 10;
    } else if (gap < 50) {
        gap = 50;
    } else if (gap < 100) {
        gap = 100;
    } else if (gap < 250) {
        gap = 250;
    ...
    }
    int minTick = (min/gap) * gap;
    if (minTick > min) { // For negative numbers.
        minTick -= gap;
    }
    int maxTick = (max/gap) * gap;
    if (maxTick > min) { // Negative, and ceiling.
        maxTick += gap;
    }
    int ngap = (maxTick - minTick) / gap;
    int[] ticks = new int[ngaps + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= ngaps; ++i) {
        ticks[i] = minTick + i * gap;
    }
    return ticks;
}
```